# Open Source projects that need mirrors?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, traffic

I have an idle web server with unlimited traffic running until January 9th, 2011.

An answerer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/185761/productive-uses-for-an-idle-web-server) had the idea of offering to host mirrors for Open Source projects.

Does anybody know of Open Source projects that have such massive mirroring needs that it's worth the effort to set another one up for this relatively short time span?

Does anybody know some sort of site or list for this purpose?

I hope this is not off-topic. I thought Server Fault would be the best place to ask, I apologize in advance if it isn't.

Comment: You should check out one of the privacy endorsing open source projects. It allows people on China (or any other country that regulates free speech and other civil rights) to browse the internet freely. I can't remember their names but google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Facebook Mirror Site](http://mirror.facebook.net/)

Mirror any of the projects on the facebook mirror site, Most projects are critical open source projects which can always use extra bandwidth.